# Changing The Download Path After Opening Selenium Firefox Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a collection of files that i download with a loop. I want to folder these files separately. Before the browser opens, I can change the default download path with the options parameter. However, I want to folder the files I will download separately after the browser is opened.

Can you please help?

`

```
optns = Options()
optns.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
optns.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
optns.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Users/emrevolkanucar/Work/Ekap Py/Files")
optns.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=optns)

???
optns.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Users/emrevolkanucar/Work/Ekap Py/Files")
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that.
Once `driver` object instance is created by `browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=optns)` you can no more change it settings.
The only ways you can do here are:

1. re-define `optns.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Users/emrevolkanucar/Work/Ekap Py/Files")` and then create a **new** `driver` instance. I'm not sure you really want to do that.
2. After downloading files to defined (or default) downloading folder you can programmatically move those file to separate target folders. This approach seems better.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second method makes a lot of sense. I think I will do so.